# Nix how to use alternative store path for CI caching

Tags: nix

Many CI providers give you a directory whose contents are retained across builds and you can use that as a cache. Everything that is stored elsewhere is lost. This means that any artefacts that are created during a nix-build that are placed in the nix store (`/nix/store`) are lost. I'm trying to figure out how to convince nix to prefer that other cache directory over the global `/nix/store`. However the documentation is a bit lacking.

What I've tried so far:

- Add `file:///the/path` to substituters and then `nix copy --to` that path. However I discovered that nix only creates some metadata files in that directory and copies the actual derivation into `/nix/store`. That's not what I want.
- Use `local?root=/the/path` instead of the file:// url (btw, this syntax is not documented anywhere, I only found it in a single github issue!). That made nix copy the whole derivation to that folder, but I couldn't figure out how to convince `nix-build` to actually consult that store during build.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to use something along the lines of `nix run --store ~/my-nix nixpkgs.hello -c hello --greeting 'Hi everybody!'`? The [installation guide](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Nix_Installation_Guide) points to uses of `--store` for such a use case, as well as some sections in the manual: [1](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#chap-distributed-builds), [2](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-relnotes-2.0).

An example of this can be found in `nix run`'s [tests](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/98f3c75a0e16f5aaaecb25a46f988580efb04d19/tests/run.sh).

There are also the environment variables `NIX_STORE_DIR` which might be of use? It's documented in `nix-shell --help`.

There's also several issues in the Nix repo, here's [an interesting discussion](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/1971).

Comment: `NIX_STORE_DIR` is usually a bad choice, since it generates new .drv files with different output and dependency paths; that forces everything to be built from scratch (all the way back to the bootstrap bash, gcc, etc.). The `--store` argument uses namespaces to bind-mount over the normal `/nix/store` path, which avoids this issue.